# Is it possible to hide the Technical Debt metric from SonarQube dashboard, entirely?

Tags: sonarqube, technical-debt

I understand that the Technical Debt metric became part of SonarQube after it was a plugin, but I would like to remove it from the dashboard completely, and only show other metrics. Is that possible from the dashboard settings? if not, I appreciate any directions on what parts of the source code have to be edited.

Answer (score 3):

Technical Debt is a core feature of SonarQube, so there's no reason why it should be possible to remove it from the main "pages" of the SonarQube web application.

If you want to hide this, you should first ask yourself why. Indeed, technical debt was not invented by SonarQube, this is a famous and widely spread concept that has been there for [more than a decade](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TechnicalDebt.html). With this concept come good practices for software development. So again, trying to hide this in SonarQube is a bit weird.

Also, I highly discourage you to fork the code of SonarQube and write your own version just for this. Think 2 seconds how difficult it will be for you to maintain your fork, and I'm sure you will forget this idea as fast as it came to your mind.

Comment: I totally agree with what you said. Basically, I'm trying to introduce the idea of source code quality analysis "gradually" to the students around me. Technical Debt has been always a point of conflict since people have different understandings of it! My idea this time is to focus on what we all agree on such as duplications, coverage, and so on. Later, when people are ready, I can introduce TD.

Comment: In the view below, you were able to hide TD tab and others. How can I customize such view/dashboard? https://nemo.sonarqube.org/governance?id=MASTER_PROJECT

Comment: I really appreciate the help.

Comment: There's a very good reason @Fabrice and that's that it can be completely misleading by default, especially when presented to a Mgmt team when not an accurate figure. It appears to be a lot of effort to make this a realistic number, particularly in a legacy environment and it should either be possible to make it accurate easily or disable it. 
Forgive me if incorrect, but as I understand it Custom Java rules are needed to change the Remediation Cost which is a non-trivial effort https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Coding+Rule+Guidelines#CodingRuleGuidelines-Evaluationoftheremediationcost